# Read multiple files from folder in perl

Tags: perl

I'm pretty new on perl and in need for some help, basically what I want is a program that reads all .txt files from a folder, doing the script and throw the output in a new folder with a new name. Everything works when I'm working with one file at the time, specifying the name of the file.. But I can't get it to work with all of the files in the folder. This is how far I've gotten.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Path::Class;
use autodie;

use File::Find;

my @now       = localtime();
my $timeStamp = sprintf(
  "%04d%02d%02d-%02d:%02d:%02d",
  $now[5] + 1900,
  $now[4] + 1,
  $now[3], $now[2], $now[1], $now[0]);    #A function that translates time

my %wordcount;

my $dir = "/home/smenk/.filfolder";
opendir(DIR, $dir) || die "Kan inte öppna $dir: $!";
my @files = grep { /txt/ } readdir(DIR);
closedir DIR;

my $new_dir  = dir("/home/smenk/.result");       # Reads in the folder for save
my $new_file = $new_dir->file("$timeStamp.log"); # Reads in the new file timestamp variable

open my $fh,  '<', $dir      or die "Kunde inte öppna '$dir' $!";
open my $fhn, '>', $new_file or die "test '$new_file'";

foreach my $file (@files) {
  open(FH, "/home/smenk/.filfolder/$file") || die "Unable to open $file - $!\n";
  while (<FH>) {

  }
  close(FH);
}

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  foreach my $str (split /\s+/, $line) {
    $wordcount{$str}++;
  }
}

my @listing = (sort { $wordcount{$b} <=> $wordcount{$a} } keys %wordcount)[0 .. 9];

foreach my $str (@listing) {
  my $output = $wordcount{$str} . " $str\n";
  print $fhn $output;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you have a typo here: `open (FH, "/home/smenk/.filfolde/$file")`. `.filfolde` should be `.filfolder`, no?

Comment: Fixed that one thanks, still getting empty files tho

Comment: Is there something you plan on doing with the file content? I wonder why a simple system command to move all the text files from one directory to another wouldn't suffice...

Comment: You are mixing so many different things all together here. If you are going to use, for example, `Path::Class::dir`, you don't need `opendir`/`readdir`.

Comment: Well you're never writing anything to `$fhn`, so it's creating files with no contents.

Comment: and `$fh` is opening a directory as though it was a file, which can't do anything useful. The only reason it doesn't cause problems is because you never use that one either.

Comment: Ryan - Indeed it is, at this point I want to get data from the files in the folder, go thro the function which basically lists the top 10 used words in the file, then print them out in a new file, in a new folder. And you're right about $fhn and $fh - They did earlier get files but as they gave no error Ieft them there for the time beeing. Thanks so far, cleaning up the code some.

Comment: On Stackoverflow, you thank by voting answers up, and checking the one that helped you the most.

Comment: Alright, I did check it but don't have enough reputation to vote it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simplest skeleton for the reading part using [Path::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class) (see also [dir](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class::dir) and [file](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class::file):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Path::Class;

my $src = dir("/home/smenk/.filfolder");

my @txt_files = grep /[.] txt\z/x, $src->children;

for my $txt_file ( @txt_files ) {
    my $in = $txt_file->openr;
    while (my $line = <$in>) {
        print "OUT: $line";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did use this as skeleton and implemented my own code (after some cleaning) and it's now working exactly as I want it to!

Comment: dead links to **dir** and **file**

Answer (score 1):

You can also use another great module [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny), for dir/file operations and the [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) for the date/time functions - like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Tiny;
use Time::Piece;

my @txtfiles  = path("/home/smenk/.filfolder")->children(qr/\.txt\z/);

my $outdir = path("home/smenk/.result");
$outdir->mkpath;    #create the dir...
my $t = localtime;
my $outfile = $outdir->child($t->strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.txt"));
$outfile->touch;

my @outdata;
for my $infile (@txtfiles) {
    my @lines = $infile->lines({chomp => 1});

    #do something with lines and create the output @data
    push @outdata, scalar @lines;
}

$outfile->append({truncate => 1}, map { "$_\n" } @outdata); #or spew;
```